# Event call at the end of HTTP call

Tags: javascript, typescript, http, angular6, dom-events

I'm developing a web application using Angular 6. I have a problem: I don't have much experience with **http calls**. My problem is this: In a certain method of a component I make an asynchronous call, like this:

```
this.http.get(url, config).pipe(
    map(response => {
        this.options = response;
    }),
).subscribe();
```

Since it's an asynchronous call, the view of my component doesn't make the data visible immediately, and I need to refresh it.
I would like to know if there is an event (similar to the lifecycle hook events) that triggers when the http call is over. In this way I could refresh only once and at the right time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.subscribe` method is an observable's way to trigger the operation and listen to its events and completion.

```
this.http.get(url, config).pipe(
    map(response => {
        this.options = response;
    }),
).subscribe(() => console.log('Got data here, you know that the request is done'));
```

In general you can think of an observable (like the one `http.get` returns)   like an event emitter for a single event through `.subscribe` + the ability to add complex pipe operations.